# Copying a List Item with Different Field Names

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, workflow

currently I'm trying to copy from one list to another.  However I have an issue in that the field names are different and can't really change without causing more headaches (example: First Name is FName on the other list) .  I'm wondering what have people done to move list items when this is the case.  I could always resort to a custom development script but was hoping to avoid this.

One theory I had and wondered if anyone tried is something of a "junction table" that would have 2 fields such as First Name and Fname with Fname being a lookup to First Name.  Then do a multi-step copy in the workflow, does this work?  Thanks!

This is using MOSS 2007 with SharePoint Designer workflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you're going to be able to get around this without script since the column names are different.  Sorry it wasn't the answer you were looking for.

Comment: after some research, me neither :-/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "Copy item" action in SPD workflow, use "Create item". This will give you the junction table you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the list you want to copy the items from, and then select:

**Actions, Export to Spreadsheet**.

This will then enable you to save this data to a file called: **owssvr.iqy**

You then open this file with Microsoft Excel, and then **select** (highlight) the data that you want to export into your other list, and **copy**. [Do not copy the data underneath the columns 'Item Type' and 'Path'.]

Leave Excel open for the moment. Now you can go your your other list, and select:

**Actions, Edit in Datasheet, then Paste your data.** Even better if both lists have columns in the same order.

Once done, all you do is select **Actions, Show In Standard View.** That's it!

Hope that helps.

Regards, Ash

Comment: No, this is using WORKFLOWS, not just copy and paste...

Comment: OK, I see. Sorry, my fault for not realising.